# Cannot use import statement outside a module CPanel Node JSApp

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, cpanel, es6-modules

I try to add an NodeJS/Express server as a NodeJS on my CPanel account.
I use ESModules and my server works well on local, I can start it and everything functions but when I configure it on CPanel I get this page.
[image]

When I go to the server logs, I see that my server returned this error :
[image]

I don't understand because my server works and local and I have { type : "module" } in my package.json and { module : "ESNext", target : "ESNext" } in my tsconfig.json.

My package.json :

```
"name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.ts",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ts-node --esm index.ts",
    "dev": "nodemon index.ts",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@notionhq/client": "^2.2.1",
    "@types/pdfkit": "^0.12.8",
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.0",
    "cloudinary": "^1.27.1",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.5",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-fileupload": "^1.2.1",
    "handlebars": "^4.7.7",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.0",
    "knex": "^2.3.0",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "nodemailer": "^6.8.0",
    "pdfkit": "^0.13.0",
    "pdfkit-table": "^0.1.99",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^4.1.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.13",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "@types/express-fileupload": "^1.4.1",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.1",
    "@types/nodemailer": "^6.4.7",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1"
  }
}
```

My tsconfig.json :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "lib": ["esnext"],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowJs": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "strict": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "typeRoots": ["src/types", "node_modules/@types"],
  },
  "ts-node": {
    "require": ["tsconfig-paths/register"]
  },
  "include": ["*", "src/*", "src/**/*", "src/***/**/*", "./custom.d.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

My index.ts :

```
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import express from "express";
import cors from "cors";
import fileUpload from "express-fileupload";
import cookieParser from "cookie-parser";
import router from "./src/routes/index.js";
dotenv.config();

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.enable("trust proxy");
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: process.env.ORIGIN?.split(","),
    methods: ["GET", "POST", "DELETE", "PUT"],
    credentials: true,
  })
);
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(fileUpload());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use("/", router);

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listen on port ${port}`));
```

Comment: Did you overcome this issue? If so, how did you get your Import statements working?